# ValueError at /feed/post/5/comment/ The view feed.views.add_comment_to_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am using this exact code in another project, the only difference is that I have changed the model names, urls patterns, and template names since it is a different project. However, I am getting this error and I have no idea why. I am trying to bring the user to a detail page that has both the post and any comments on the post, as well as a link that takes to a page that allows the user to add a comment to the post.

app Views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(UserPost,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('feed:post_detail', pk=userpost.pk)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'feed/comment_form.html',{'form':form})
```

userpost_detail.html (post_detail in urls)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1 class="posttitle">{{ userpost.title }}</h1>

    <p class="postcontent">{{ userpost.post_body }}</p>

    {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user == post.author %}
        <a class="link" href="{% url 'feed:edit_post' post.id %}">Edit Post</a>
    {% endif %}

    <hr>


    <a href="{% url 'feed:add_comment' userpost.id %}">Add Comment</a>

    <div class="container">
        {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <br>
            {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
                {{ comment.create_date }}
                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                </a>
                <p>{{ comment.comment_body }}</p>
                <p>Posted By: {{ comment.author }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
            <p>No Comments</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

comment_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>New Comment</h1>
    <form class="post-form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Add Comment</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Traceback and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view feed.views.add_comment_to_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view does not return anything if the request is not a POST.

The problem is one of indentation. The last three lines - from `else` onwards - need to be moved back one level.

Comment: I now have an integrity error `IntegrityError at /feed/post/5/comment/
NOT NULL constraint failed: feed_usercomment.author_id` but other than that it works now, thanks.

Comment: You presumably need to set `comment.author = request.user` before saving.